# After a cleanup i get wrong warnings in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

After i cleaned a Projekt i got wrong warnings

```
publi*c class Hand*Measurement {


pub*lic HandMeasurement*(String path, HandMeasurementUi userInterface) {
```

everything betwen the " * " is with yellow underlines and gives warnings from a previous version of the Code. I tryed to close and open the Projekt and load a copy of it.

Is there a error Log or something i need to reset?

Comment: Looks like a typical eclipse bug. Should be gone when you restart eclipse.

Comment: Sadly its still be there. Restarting Eclipse and the PC dindt work.

Comment: Clean -> Build will make it go.

Comment: @holmes840 I think it's Project -> Build but maybe that's depending on the version.

Comment: I use Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 its strange that there are 2 ways to clean an projekt that do different things.

Comment: @Gumbo By "Clean -> Build" , I meant first clean the project and then build it. I think eclipse keeps this thing same in all versions but it is possible that they changed in newer version:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to clean the project *Menu:Project/Clean* and make sure that *Build Automatically* in project menu is checked.

Comment: Strange but that was the thing what made the Problem. Neverless... it worked. Thanks! EDIT: Is there a difference betwenn "rightclick on the Projekt - clean" and "menue: project/clean" ?

Comment: In the dialog (from the project menu) you can choose between all and selected projects to clean. (I don't have clean in the context menu.)